# why done runs earlier before supertest request on sequelize?

Tags: jestjs, sequelize.js, supertest

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

    request(app)
        .get("/videos")
        .expect(200)
        .end(async (err,res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                done();
            } else {
                console.log(res.body);
                done(); // <- this is the question line
            }
```

If I take off the done from the code, the test will print the result, but if I have `done` there, sequelize still print but there is no res.body print on the console.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the asynchronous nature of javascript.

By default, Jest tests complete once they reach the end of their execution. That means this test will not work as intended:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

    request(app)
        .get("/videos")
        .expect(200)
        .end(async (err,res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                // done();
            } else {
                console.log(res.body);
                // done();
            }
```

The problem is that the test will complete as soon as function completes asynchronosly.

Moving to, after putting done()

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');

    request(app)
        .get("/videos")
        .expect(200)
        .end(async (err,res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                done();
            } else {
                console.log(res.body);
                done();
            }
```

And then, in that case, it waits for the done function before finishing the test.

For more details. Please check [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous).

I hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: I commented done in the first snippet and not in 2nd snippet. So basically it's doesn't wait for the done before finishing the test.

Comment: My question is actually, without done(), res.body print successfully, but with done() it won't print; how can I print and done? without done the program will throw timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `async` from `.end(async (err,res) => {` line so the callback is not considered asynchronous anymore.